# How to open new context menu on Windows 11 using keyboard only

Tags: context-menu, windows-11

Just noticed that on Windows 11 both <kbd>Menu</kbd> key on the keyboard and <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> opens classic old context menu. New context menu is shown only after right clicking.

Is there any way to open new context menu using keyboard?

---

UPDATE: in version 22H2 of Windows 11 the <kbd>Menu</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> the behavior changed and both open **new** context menu now

Answer (score 1):

Great question!  I assume you did the same exercise that I did -- Looked through pretty much every list of Windows 11 shortcut keys on the web (including [Microsoft's](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec)) and come up short.  Of course, it's entirely possible that we're both just missing it.  In that case, someone else will come along and give us the right answer so I can delete this one.

Or it's possible that it's an oversight on the part of the Windows team at Microsoft.  In that case, I'm guessing they'll correct it before too long ...

In the meantime, I have two possible workarounds.

- First, I'm not a fan of this one, but the "easiest" solution I can come up with is to use the Mouse Keys feature (built in to Windows):

  - Turn on Mouse Keys in Settings
  - Press the numeric keypad's <kbd>-</kbd> key to toggle right-click mode.
  - Press either <kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>/</kbd> when the desktop is focused to perform a right-click which will show the new context menu.

  Of course, this takes over your numeric keypad.  So it's a nonstarter if you need that functionality.  At least you can still use the arrow keys by toggling <kbd>NumLock</kbd> off.

  Side note (from experience):  If you are using Windows 11 through RDP (Remote Desktop), then it is the *client* computer that will need Mouse Keys enabled, not the host to which you are connected.  This will work even if the client is Windows 10 connecting to a Windows 11 host.
- A better answer *might* be to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).  Pick any hotkey you want and use it to send a Right-click to the current mouse location.  This script example uses <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>:

  ```
  #NoEnv
  #Warn
  SendMode Input
  SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
  #F10::
  Send {Click 0 0 Relative Right}
  return
  ```

  Note that it's been a few years since I coded in AutoHotkey's scripting language, so I'm sure there are improvements that could be made.  One would be to detect if the mouse is over the Windows desktop and only take over the shortcut key if so.

  However, this is a workable first attempt, in that it seems to work for displaying the new desktop context-menu using the keyboard in Windows 10.  Just be on the lookout in case it interferes with other apps.

Answer (score -1):

The keyboard combination <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> opens start menu's context-menu in Windows 11.